# Почему у меня в гугл хроме в консоле не написано что объект это объект

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, консоль

Прилагаю скрин. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Справа моя консоль и у меня перед объектом не написано что это объект ?ПОчему? И как сделать чтобы было написано "объект"?

PS Также например когда массив у меня просто [] (квадратные скобочки) и нет слова Array

Comment: потому что матюки туда пишешь

Comment: Но зачем? И так видно, что это объект

Comment: хочетсяяяяяяя...